# ember data: customize serializer used by toJSON

Tags: serialization, ember.js, ember-data

In my ember-data-using application I have an application serializer (mainly to take care of polymorphic relationships properly). However, its not used when I call `toJSON()` on a model instance, its not used -- rather the default JSONSerializer is used instead.

How can I customize the serializer used by toJSON()?

Comment: Looking at the Ember Data code, it would seem that I could override Model.toJSON or monkeypatch DS.JSONSerializer... I'd reluctantly accept that as an answer, as it seems to only one possible, but if there is actually a cleaner way, I'll be happier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i hope i understood properly your question...

Well, If you want to get the same result as in your `ApplicationSerializer` just call `this.serialize()` in your model.

If you want absolutely use the `toJSON` method without overwriting the default `DS.Model` of your whole app you can still make something like that :

```
App.CustomModel = DS.Model.extend({
  toJSON: function(){
    return this.serialize();
  }  
});
```

and then make all the concerned model extend this `CustomModel`

```
App.Color = App.CustomModel.extend({
  name : DS.attr("string")
});
```

here is a working [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gawagiqifu/20/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Indeed -- what I want is for the toJSON() method to return proper JSON for the model ... this is what I thought I had to do, but thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking to customize toJSON output for a particular model, you can do the following in your `models/user.js` file:

```
DS.Model.extend({
  toJSON: function(options){
    let json = this._super(options);
    // Do something with json
    return json;
  }  
});
```

Magic of Ember Object structure. In my case, I had to remove a property from `toJSON` response if it doesn't have value and this worked.